# Angular and repeated jquery-ui dialogs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to write a directive, to have as many dialogs open as there are elements in a (dynamic) list.

If I apply the dialog() in "link", jquery-ui moves the div to the end of the document's body and wraps other elements around it. This works for the first instance in the list. However, when a second instance is added, the div for the first instance is yanked back (without the wrappers) to the place it was initially positioned.

```
myMod.directive('instanceDialog', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div>Directived instance of {{instance}}</div>',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(element).dialog().dialog('open');
            },0);
        },
    };
});
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnurfos/tga6h1r0/1): click on add twice: one of the 2 dialogs is empty, and there's is stuff displayed where there should not be)

How can I make this work ?

Edit: I am starting to realize that there is a conflict between a directive and jquery-ui's dialog, as both want to control/own the dom elements (and one is local, whereas the other is global). At this point I am trying to use an angular service instead, but am still interested in understanding how things work (or don't), namely here: why both dialog and ng-repeat are moving nodes around.

Comment: So is the intention that you provide the directive a list of configuration objects that specify how to display each dialog? Does this list get modified by outside code, and if so, does it need to modify the list of dialogs shown?

Comment: The intention is more to have different contents than different configurations. The list is populated by "outside" code like the Add button in the example.

Comment: I am not sure I understand "does it need to modify the list of dialogs shown?". I simply want to have 2-way binding so that the javascript list (instances) is in sync with the list of opened widgets (I will of course need to add a close handler, but that's another problem).

Comment: So what does each item in the list represent? I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Each item in the list represents an opened dialog. I want a new dialog to open when I push an item into the list (and previously opened dialogs to remain open).

Comment: By the way I fixed the fiddle, because it was broken somehow (it didn't show any dialog whereas my problem is buggy dialogs).

Comment: Hi Gnurfos, i'm facing same situation. What was your solution for this? Could you share the updated jsfiddle link or describe the way you used service instead?. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HoaNguyen I did not find a solution for this precise problem. What I did was move away to something else than dialogs. It was bad for user interaction to have several dialogs at the same time, anyway.